# How can i print my jquery variable value in to a div however i got my value in variable named as count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**i have a selector structure like that**

```
 <span class="pr_count">Characters <a class="cont"> </a></span>
```

and i have my function something like that gets value when i check in console but didn't print in my HTML selector

```
var count = $("#cout_text").text().length ; 

$(".pr_count .cont").html("Characters" '+' count);
```

Comment: $(".pr_count .cont").html("Characters" +  count);

Comment: thanx man it works ..

Comment: I see LostMyGlasses wrot a similar answer. Please accept his answer and motivate us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error. The `+` operand must not be surrounded by quotes. Try with this:

```
$(".pr_count .cont").html("Characters " + count);
```